# DatabaseEvent event.snapshot.value is not printing any value

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am new t flutter and following documentations as most of the courses and videos are outdated but DatabaseEvent event.snapshot.value is not printing any value
This is my data is RealTime Database of firebase and I want to read it.

```
users
  3I4SCTCeyJVKWYvdnU2NHLmoTYV2
      email: "riomobility16@gmail.com"
      name: "riomobility"
      phone: "+923031521515"
```

this is my code: Reference is getting printed but DatabaseEvent event.snapshot.value is not. Please help thank you

```
 DatabaseReference reference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("user").child(userId).child("name");

    DatabaseEvent event = await reference.once();

    
    print(reference.key);
    print(reference.parent!.key);

    print(event.snapshot.value);
```

printed results:

```
I/flutter (19657): name
I/flutter (19657): 3I4SCTCeyJVKWYvdnU2NHLmoTYV2
I/flutter (19657): null
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print all of `event.snapshot`, or at least `event.snapshot.exists` and `event.snapshot.key`?

Comment: event.snapshot prints "Instance of 'DataSnapshot'"...... event.snapshot.exits prints "false" .... event.snapshot.key prints "name"...

Comment: From that it looks like `/user/$userId/name` does not exist after all. It might be worth checking whether your client is actually connected to the database, whether you're using disk caching/offline persistence, and if you accidentally have any spaces before/after the UID in your database key itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying everything, nothing worked but finally something did as I was shuffling my code. So,

```
DatabaseReference reference =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("users").child(userId);

    DatabaseEvent event = await reference.once();

    DataSnapshot snap = event.snapshot;

print(snap.value);
```

not this printing value..

I thought even.snapshot.value is the same as above code but it wasn't.